# Serializing & Unwrap the Map object in POJO using Jackson annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a POJO with a property named paramMap as Map type.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonUnwrapped;

@JsonTypeInfo(include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use=Id.NAME)
public class Pojo {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Map<String, Object> getParamMap() {
        return paramMap;
    }

    public void setParamMap(Map<String, Object> paramMap) {
        this.paramMap = paramMap;
    }
```

consider i have populated some values in the map, now i want to serialize this and unwrap the property name `paramMap` .

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "Pojo": {
        "name": "value1",
        "age": 12,
        "date": "12/02/2015"
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
{
    "Pojo": {
        "paramMap": {
            "name": "value1",
            "age": 12,
            "date": "12/02/2015"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html), Using the Jackson annotation `@JsonAnyGetter` in the getter method of `getParamMap()` we can get the expected out put.

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getParamMap() {
    return paramMap;
}
```

**Note:** This is is still open in Jackson project [Issue #171](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/171)
Thanks ***Tatu Saloranta*** author of the post